# try/catch error handling

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to create a script to delete all files out of `%temp%`. It works but now I need to get rid of the errors. Below is what I have but I'm still getting errors. Any ideas?

```
try
   {
      Get-Childitem $Env:temp | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
   }
Catch
   {
   }
```

Comment: When you say _get rid of errors_ what do you want to do about them? You can just ignore them with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of files in temp can be in use or otherwise inaccessible for removable as that is the scratch space for processes to leave data.

Most common cmdlets support `-ErrorAction` so that you don't have to the change the default one and risk missing an important error. In your case you can use ...

```
Get-Childitem $Env:temp | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Since you are not generating terminating errors which is what `Try` is for you can just remove the block entirely.

---

FWIW if you really do need try/catch make sure you use terminating errors

```
try{
    Get-ChildItem $Env:temp | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch{
    # Handle Stuff
    Write-Host "Removal not 100% successful"
}
```